# Pandas create columns with counts from column with array of strings

Tags: pandas

would like to create columns that correspond to counts of strings that appear in a column that is an array of strings.

for example

```
idx | strings 
1   | ['a','b','c']
2   | ['b','d','e']
```

to

```
idx | 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'e'
1   |  1  |  1  |  1  |  0  |  0
2   |  0  |  1  |  0  |  1  |  1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `explode` then `get_dummies`

```
out = df.join(df.pop('strings').explode().str.get_dummies().groupby(level=0).sum())
```

Comment: Or if the DF is as simple as the OP shows - maybe something like: `pd.get_dummies(df.explode('strings'), prefix='', prefix_sep='').groupby(level=0).sum()`

Comment: what kind of strings would this work for?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Counter`

```
from collections import Counter
pd.DataFrame(df.strings.apply(Counter).to_list(), index=df.index)
#      a  b    c    d    e
# 1  1.0  1  1.0  NaN  NaN
# 2  NaN  1  NaN  1.0  1.0
```